# Make a list of letters of the alphabet, in random colors, with frames having random background colors

Tags: functions, style, frame

```
 Style[#, Background -> RandomColor[], FontColor -> RandomColor[]] & /@
  Framed /@ Alphabet[]
```

> This is the result I want

[image]

> This is the result I'm getting

[image]

> I need output with default frame border color(black). but can't find the right solution. please help with my study.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without changing your code too much:

```
Style[#, Background -> RandomColor[], 
   FontColor -> 
    RandomColor[]] & /@ (Framed[#, FrameStyle -> Black, 
     Background -> RandomColor[]] & /@ Alphabet[])
```

---

However, it is better to apply `Background` to `Framed` only for individual cases and not to `Style` at all.

```
SeedRandom[1];
Framed[
   Style[#, RandomColor[]]
   , FrameStyle -> Black
   , Background -> RandomColor[]
   ] & /@ Alphabet[]
```

[image]